# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException AES

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am using `AESCrypt` `(gradle :compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1')`
to encrypt and decrypt the data.

```
  TextView  tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.demotext);
    String encrypted="",decrypted="";
    try {
        encrypted = AESCrypt.encrypt("password","This is the best thing to go by");

        decrypted = AESCrypt.decrypt("password",encrypted);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("EncryptedData:"+encrypted);
    System.out.println("DecryptedData:"+decrypted);
    tv.setText("Encrypted:"+encrypted +"\n"+"Decrypted:"+decrypted);
```

The code works perfectly fine in this case, I get the same input as decrypted text.

But, when I try to use already encrypted string using the same method (**AES**) from the site http://aesencryption.net/ as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

And copy paste that encrypted text like:

```
decrypted = AESCrypt.decrypt("password","sttA+FbNm3RkTovjHI8CcAdStXiMl45s29Jqle+y+pA=");
```

And then run the code then I get error saying :

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e06b065:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:BAD_DECRYPT
```

[image]

But when I use the decrypted text into the same site it works fine as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

```
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't compare code that you wrote to some online encryptor where you don't know their code. Why would this be even interesting to you? The site you're referencing is terrible. It propagates not very secure code in two languages that are not compatible.

Comment: becase i want to encrypt like 1MB  json and store it to Android Mobile.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: Have a look at JNCryptor

Comment: ok sure,i will give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to the algorithm to convert the passphrase 'password' to SecretKeySpec

This is the algorithm in AESCrypt

```
private static SecretKeySpec GenerateKey (final String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {    
     final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance (HASH_ALGORITHM);
     byte [] bytes = password.getBytes ("UTF-8");
     digest.update (bytes, 0, bytes.length);
     byte [] key = digest.digest ();

     log ("SHA-256 key" key);

     SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec (key, "AES");
     secretKeySpec return;
  }
```

And this is the (Java) example aesencryption.net

```
sha = MessageDigest.getInstance ("SHA-1");
key = sha.digest (key);
key = Arrays.copyOf (key, 16); // Use only first 128 bit
SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec (key, "AES");
```

The first one applies SHA256 hashing, and the second SHA-1 after completing up to 16 bytes, so the key is different.

I think you are encrypting and decrypting AES in the right way. You do not need to change anything.

But if you want to be compatible with aesencryption.net, you need to implement the same key generation algorithm. The code is not too good. I try to summarize

```
//Code from aesencryption.net 
// Generate key
MessageDigest sha = null;
key = myKey.getBytes ("UTF-8");
sha = MessageDigest.getInstance ("SHA-1");
key = sha.digest (key);
key = Arrays.copyOf (key, 16); // Use only first 128 bit
SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec (key, "AES");

public static String encrypt (String strToEncrypt) {
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES / ECB / PKCS5Padding");
     cipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKey);
     Base64.encodeBase64String return (cipher.doFinal (strToEncrypt.getBytes ("UTF-8"))));
}

public static String decrypt (String strToDecrypt) {
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES / ECB / PKCS5PADDING");
     cipher.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecretKey);
     return new String (cipher.doFinal (Base64.decodeBase64 (strToDecrypt))));
}
```

I can also provide my own code extracted from an Android app witch requires to store private user data. Data is ciphered with an AES key protected with an user passphrase

```
public static String SIMMETRICAL_ALGORITHM = "AES";

//Generate cipher key with user provided password
private static String getPassphraseSize16(String key) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
        return null;
    }
    char controlChar = '\u0014';
    String key16 = key + controlChar;
    if (key16.length() < 16) {
        while (key16.length() < 16) {
            key16 += key + controlChar;
        }
    }
    if (key16.length() > 16) {
        key16 = key16.substring(key16.length() - 16, key16.length());
    }
    return key16;
}

//AES cipher with passphrase
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] message, String passphrase)
        throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    String passphrase16 = getPassphraseSize16(passphrase);

    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passphrase16.getBytes(), SIMMETRICAL_ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(SIMMETRICAL_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(message);

    return encoded;
}

//AES decipher with passphrase
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encodedMessage, String key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    String passphrase16 = getPassphraseSize16(key);

    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passphrase16.getBytes(), SIMMETRICAL_ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(SIMMETRICAL_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte decoded[] = cipher.doFinal(encodedMessage);

    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: so  you mean i shall  generate  key and use it and not use directly?

Comment: I think you can use AESCrypt.encrypt and AESCrypt.decrypt the same way as in your example

Comment: but its not working as i have mentioned ?  can you make things clear what should i change/edit?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I have summarized the aesencryption code in the answer. AESCrypt is better choice in my opinion. I you want to be compatible with aesencryption.net, use directly their key generation code (it is full on aesencryption.net page)

Comment: as you  know what you are doing  can you please edit the answer with tested code ? that would be biggest help

Comment: public static String encrypt (String strToEncrypt) {
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES / ECB / PKCS5Padding");
     cipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKey);
     Base64.encodeBase64String return (cipher.doFinal (strToEncrypt.getBytes ("UTF-8"))));
}  what are you using that base64.encodeBase64String for?

Comment: I have included an own example of one of my android projects. It is tested.

Comment: About base64.encodeBase64String, it is copied from aesencryption.net. It really is not necessary, but I have copied it to not alter their code too much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112758/discussion-between-laxman-bhattarai-and-pedrofb).